# avaudioplayer playingsong

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I created instance `AVAudioPlayer`  but the instance is working only once like if I give

```
if(a.playing)
{
    i=1
}
else
{
     i=2
}
```

for 1st time its giving `i=1` while playing and other times its giving `i=2` while playing.

Comment: You're not completely new to this site, you should already know how to format your question. Please do so.

Comment: what do you mean by other times. are you running your code again or you are checking this condition again will the music is still playing.

Comment: checking the code again while still playing

Answer (score 0):

AVAudioPlayer reference [Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) clearly mentions this about the playing property

Important: Do not poll this property (that is, do not use it inside of a loop) in an attempt to discover when playback has stopped.
Perhaps u can try `[audioPlayer isPlaying];`